# Need help setting up WiFi on HP laptop - Ubuntu 14.04 is the OS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, internet

I am completely new to Ubuntu Mate.  I purchased a larger hard drive for my old HP laptop and installed 14.04 LTS as the only operating system.

The good news:  it works great, with a wired connection, the bad news:  I cannot seem to get the WiFi connection set up.

I have tried to install the proprietary driver, I've searched the forums and entered certain codes into the terminal, I've followed instructions that have seemed to work for others who have asked similar questions but I cannot seem to get this set up or even have my WiFi or any WiFi connection detected.

Pls let me know if I can provide any additional detail - I really appreciate any guidance you can share.

Thank you !

Joez

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Hi Chili555 - is this what you're looking for ?   Thank you for the response !  joez@joez-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
joez@joez-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Even if the keyboard light is not working, the hardware button may still work to cause your wifi to remain turned off. Try the key combination as you would on Windows and see if it works. Without knowing what HP laptop you have, it's not possible to give advice on how to enable the keyboard "hotkeys" to get e.g. that WiFi light working on your keyboard again.

Answer (score 0):

The Additional Drivers tool offers to install the proprietary Broadcom STA driver for your device. It is incorrect. With a temporary internet connection,open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

The firmware installer takes a few moments; please be patient. When it finishes, reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Hi Chili555 - thank you, I opened the terminal, entered those three codes and rebooted.  My WiFi connection is still not being detected or automatically connecting.  The wired connection is of course working.  If you're thinking everything should work at this point I am wondering if I need help editing my WiFi network connection details (WiFi, WiFi Security, IPv4 Settings, IPv6 Settings) ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any details. Network Manager should do all the work. What does this tell us? `rfkill list all`?

Comment: joez@joez-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
joez@joez-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: "Hard blocked:yes" implies that the switch or key combination, F12 or some such,  is set to disable wireless. Please find it and switch it.

Comment: Hi Chili555 - above the F12 key on my laptop there is a back lit wifi button.  When I had windows on this laptop you could touch it and the backlighting would turn from red to blue to indicate that Wifi has gone from disabled (red light) to enabled (blue light).  Right now the backlighting is red and it no longer changes to blue by touching it.  Any thoughts on how I can force it to change ?

Comment: Hi Chili555 - I found the post below on ubuntuforums.org and it worked for me but I too would like a better solution - any thoughts ?


"When I unplugged my ethernet cable and suspended my computer, then opened it back up the wifi was magically working just fine! I rebooted to see if it would stay on, and it didn't. However, I replicated the process and found that it works every time I suspend and then open back up. 
I'm glad I have some sort of wireless connection, but I would rather not have to suspend every time I want to use wifi. Any ideas?"

Comment: May I see a link to the post?

Comment: Sure - here you go !  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178085

Comment: The solution on page 3 is for an Asus laptop; you have an HP. Is the module *hp-wmi* loaded both before suspend, when it doesn't work and after, when it does? Check: `lsmod | grep wmi`.