# Wifi not working Ubuntu 14.04 Hp Pavililon 2015

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, hp

I have dual booted my Hp Pavilion notebook Model 2015-ab277cl with ubuntu 14.04 and I have not been able to get the wifi working at all or find a wifi driver on the Ubuntu. I have tried solutions from [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem) and [Need help setting up WiFi on HP laptop - Ubuntu 14.04 is the OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631334/need-help-setting-up-wifi-on-hp-laptop-ubuntu-14-04-is-the-os) but they are not working for me. I have been able to successfully use Ethernet though.

Output from lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
```

uname -a

```
Linux nathan-HP-Pavilion-Notebook 4.4.0-36-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 11:49:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   13.654418] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   14.167484] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.167504] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.167513] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.167521] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.192838] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.192850] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.192858] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.192860] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode' failed.
[   14.192862] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: It is an Intel device, it made no sense to install drivers for other adapters. Please post output of `uname -a`.

Comment: 3.19 is too old for Intel 3165.

Comment: So you upgraded the kernel. What does  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` show now?

Comment: It shows the same thing  as before <br/>  08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)

Comment: Please add the output to the question. And I do not see kernel modules. Does Wi-Fi work now? If not, add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`. And it does not show "the same thing" if you noticed. The adapter IS detected correctly now.

Comment: Did you upgrade the firmware with the command I gave. What is the firmware version? Check it by `dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware`. It should be `1.127.22`.

Comment: Yes, it is 1.144+ar3012

Comment: That is all wrong. You installed old firmware from my PPA. That is the problem. You tried blatantly wrong solutions. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a kernel that does not support this adapter.

You need to connect to internet by wire and upgrade kernel by these commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-firmware
```

Reboot after you do that.

You installed a wrong firmware from my ppa.

**You don't have a RTL8723BE device.** So it made no sense to use solutions for it.

You need to remove it and install the firmware from Ubuntu repositories. Run

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

That should install the correct firmware version, and Wi-Fi will work.

Comment: Is there anything I should try additionally after updating the kernel?

Comment: It should work, unless the required firmware is not there.

Comment: It working now thanks for the help, sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your laptop to the internet using a lan cable then look in the additional drivers pane in settings (System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers). You can choose to use a proprietary driver for your sifi card from there.

Comment: For some reason the drivers aren't registering even though they have been installed and the files are there. It says no additional drivers are available even though the files exists, I am uncertain as to why this is occurring.

Comment: I am not sure why this is. It may be a bug. I was facing a similar problem when I tried installing a proprietary nvidia driver for my graphics card. Even though the additional drivers pane was not displaying my driver, it did get installed and ubuntu was using it. I had to use the terminal to check this. You should try doing the same.

Comment: You can find drivers only for Broadcom adapters there.

Comment: @Pilot6 I know that this is unrelated to the topic here but can you please take a look at this (This is regarding your answer on  Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu and I do not have enough reputation to comment on your answer): http://askubuntu.com/questions/816726/bluetooth-device-not-working-after-patch